# TrueCrypt. auto-mount the secondary volume?

Tags: security, truecrypt

I have a system volume and a secondary volume. Both are encrypted. How I can make the secondary volume mount automatically (without asking password), when I boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Can a volume be automatically mounted whenever I log on to Windows?*
>
> Yes. To do so, follow these steps:
>
> Mount the volume (to the drive letter to which you want it to be mounted every time).
>   Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main TrueCrypt window and select 'Add to Favorites'.
>   The Favorites Organizer window should appear now. In this window, enable the option 'Mount selected volume upon logon' and click OK.
>
> Then, when you log on to Windows, you will be asked for the volume password (and/or keyfiles) and if it is correct, the volume will be mounted.
>
> Alternatively, if the volumes are partition/device-hosted and if you do not need to mount them to particular drive letters every time, you can follow these steps:
>   Select Settings > Preferences. The Preferences window should appear now.
>   In the section 'Actions to perform upon logon to Windows', enable the option 'Mount all devices-hosted TrueCrypt volumes' and click OK.
>
> **Note: TrueCrypt will *not* prompt you for a password if you have enabled caching of the pre-boot authentication password (Settings > 'System Encryption') and the volumes use the same password as the system partition/drive.**

Quoted from here:
http://www.truecrypt.org/faq